# Glassfish + Postgres can't ping connection pool

Tags: postgresql, netbeans, glassfish-3

I try to make login page for web application using Glassfish 3.1 and Postgres. I have local database (localhost:5432). This is my connection pool:

```
Pool Name:pacjentauth
Resource Type:javax.sql.DataSource
Datasource Classname:org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
Driver Classname: [nothing here]
```

portNumber, ServerName, user and password are ok.
This is error I get:

```
[#|2013-01-03T20:13:44.110+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security|_ThreadID=113;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception|#]

[#|2013-01-03T20:21:54.567+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2013-01-03T20:21:54.924+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=38;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2013-01-03T20:21:54.976+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=34;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2013-01-03T20:21:55.032+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=49;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2013-01-03T20:21:55.084+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2013-01-03T20:21:55.691+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=38;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Redirecting to /common/security/realms/realms.jsf|#]

[#|2013-01-03T20:21:55.751+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=49;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...|#]

[#|2013-01-03T20:22:06.541+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.gjc.util|_ThreadID=163;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5099 : Wrong class name or classpath for Datasource Object 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.getDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:285)
    at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.constructDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:114)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(ManagedConnectionFactory.java:1307)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:163)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:102)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getUnpooledConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:697)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.testConnectionPool(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:426)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.pingConnectionPool(ConnectorRuntime.java:1086)
    at org.glassfish.connectors.admin.cli.PingConnectionPool.execute(PingConnectionPool.java:130)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateExecCommand.executeCommand(TemplateExecCommand.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateCommandGetResource.processGet(TemplateCommandGetResource.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor186.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]

[#|2013-01-03T20:22:06.542+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service|_ThreadID=163;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ pacjentauth ], Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource|#]

[#|2013-01-03T20:22:06.546+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=161;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json'; attrs = '{id=pacjentauth}'|#]
```

any ideas what could be wrong? If there's not enough information plz tell me what you need.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, it was all about jar. I copied these files:

```
postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4
postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc3
```

to `C:\Users\epcs\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\epacjent\lib` and it finally works.

Comment: I had to additionally issue the command `$install_dir/bin/asadmin restart-domain` for this to work.

Comment: Where are those files located usually?

Answer (score 3):

Have you attempted to put a Postgres JDBC driver jar in your GlassFish lib directory? With MySQL, we had to download a MySQL JDBC driver and copy the jar file into  `/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/lib`.

Comment: and where should I put it, if I'm on windows? (sorry, webapp it's completely new thing for me)